# Allow password saving in iOS7

Tags: ios7, mobile-website

iOS7 now has support for Keychain to act as a kind of "1Password" competitor but the site I manage is popping up a dialog when users login informing them that we have "Requested Passwords Not Be Saved"

The full error is:

"Safari Will Not Save Your Password Because "thesite.com" Requested Passwords Not Be Saved"

Does anyone know what we should do to prevent this error and allow users to save their password?

Comment: Per [this answer][1] try removing `autocomplete="off"` from all forms.


  [1]: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/108002/64051

Answer (score 0):

Per John MacAdam's comment the solution was to remove autocomplete="off" from the forms.